# Difference between durations

Tags: php, datetime, time, difference

I am creating a timesheet whereby it shows expected and actual hours.

The durations are saved like the below

`23:15` - 23 hours and 15 mins

`25:45` - 25 hours and 45 mins

I need to work out the difference in hours and mins between the two (extra hours worked)

I have tried the below

```
$acutal=='23:15';
$expected=='25:45';
$start_time = new DateTime("1970-01-01 $acutal:00");
$time = $start_date->diff(new DateTime("1970-01-01 $expected:00"));
```

This does work, however when the hours are over 24:00 it throws an error (obviously because it's reading it as time)

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct():
>   Failed to parse time string (1970-01-01 25:45:00)

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you don't care about time zones and such it's probably easiest to just convert to minutes, subtract, and convert back. No need to add the complexity of creating real DateTime style objects.

Comment: @CollinD - could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the number of hours are greater than 24, and if so, add a day, and remove 24 hours.

```
$actual='23:15';
$expected='25:45';

$day = 1;
list($hrs, $min) = explode(':', $expected);
if ($hrs > 24) { $day += 1; $hrs -= 24; }

$start_time = new DateTime("1970-01-01 $actual:00");
$time = $start_time->diff(new DateTime("1970-01-$day $hrs:$min:00"));

echo $time->format('%hh %Im');
```

Output:

```
2h 30m
```

Please also note that `==` is used to compare, not to assign.

You can also change the `if ($hrs > 24)` by `while()`, if there is 48 hours or more.

---

*edit*

As pointed out by @CollinD, if the time exceed the number of days of the month, it will fail. Here is another solution:

```
$actual='23:15';
$expected='25:45';

list($hrs, $min) = explode(':', $actual);
$total1 = $min + $hrs * 60;

list($hrs, $min) = explode(':', $expected);
$diff = $min + $hrs * 60 - $total1;

$start_time = new DateTime();
$expected_time = new DateTime();
$expected_time->modify("+ $diff minutes");
$time = $start_time->diff($expected_time);

echo $time->format('%hh %Im');
```

Comment: As a heads-up, I suspect this will run into the same problem you had before if your durations exceed the number of hours in January of 1970.

Comment: You're right @CollinD, thanks. I've updated the answer to a new way to do this.

Comment: If you're already converting everything to minutes, it seems like it might be best to just remove the complexity added by using `DateTime` all-together. Durations are really just scalars with dimension time, so adding temporal context is only asking for weird edge-case trouble imo.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting comment @CollinD. (I've slightly modified the code). The `DateInterval` object allows to format, and I've used that to match to the OP original code.

Comment: @Syscall - your update returns `0h 00m` when using these variables `$actual='34:50';
$expected='22:00';`

Comment: @Shane : Please see https://3v4l.org/Qev4c : `$expected_time->modify(($diff < 0 ? '' : '+') . "$diff minutes");` or use `abs($diff)`, or check if $actual is greater than $expected and inverse them. That was because the string in `modify()` was `"+ -770 minutes"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using datetime functions but it seems a lot more straightforward to me to treat the times as string, use split or explode to get hours and minutes, convert to integers, get the difference in minutes and convert it back to hours and minutes (integer divide by 60 and remainder).

```
$t1=explode(':',$expected);
$t2=explode(':',$actual);
$d=60*($t1[0]-$t2[0])+t1[1]-t2[1];
$result=str_pad(floor($d/60),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($d%60,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by keeping track of the number of minutes worked - this will be exact and will also allow you to show negative differences.

```php
<?php
// get the difference in H:mm between two H:mm 
function diff_time($actual, $expected) {
    $diff_mins = mins($actual) - mins($expected);

    return format_mins($diff_mins);
}

// convert a HH:mm to number of minutes
function mins($t) {
    $parts = explode(':', $t);

    return $parts[0] * 60 + $parts[1];
}

// convert number of minutes into HH:mm
function format_mins($m) {
    $mins = $m % 60;
    $hours = ($m - $mins) / 60;

    // format HH:mm
    return $hours . ':' . sprintf('%02d', abs($mins));
}

var_dump(diff_time('23:15', '25:45'));
var_dump(diff_time('25:15', '23:45'));
```

This outputs:

```
string(5) "-2:30"
string(4) "1:30"
```

.. first, 2:30 less than expected, for the second 1:30 more than expected.